# Terraform workspaces different variables

Tags: azure, terraform

Can we create different variables file for  different workspaces?
how to create variables for each environment in terraform workspaces?

Comment: Are you talking about Terraform cloud or Terraform open source? Because workspaces have different meaning in one and the other.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know how to use this in different workspaces for Terraform open-source, that should not be hard to achieve. For example, say you have three environments, namely `dev`, `qa` and `prod`. You would create three separate `.tfvars` files, i.e., `dev.tfvars`, `qa.tfvars` and `prod.tfvars`. Then, when running the plan and apply commands, you would do the following:

```bash
terraform plan -var-file=`terraform workspace show`.tfvars
```

or alternatively:

```bash
terraform plan -var-file=$(terraform workspace show).tfvars
```

where the `terraform workspace show` will be the workspace you are currently in. That means you would have to switch to the desired workspace previously with `terraform workspace select <workspace>`. However, I urge you to reconsider using the same code for different environments which are using workspaces as a means of separation of concerns. From the terraform documentation about workspaces [1]:

> In particular, organizations commonly want to create a strong separation between multiple deployments of the same infrastructure serving different development stages (e.g. staging vs. production) or different internal teams. In this case, the backend used for each deployment often belongs to that deployment, with different credentials and access controls. Named workspaces are not a suitable isolation mechanism for this scenario.

> Instead, use one or more re-usable modules to represent the common elements, and then represent each instance as a separate configuration that instantiates those common elements in the context of a different backend. In that case, the root module of each configuration will consist only of a backend configuration and a small number of module blocks whose arguments describe any small differences between the deployments.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces

Comment: if we have different workspaces not identical ?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You would just use conditional syntax in that case. Something like `terrafrom.workspace == var.env` or something like that.

Comment: But without any code it's pretty hard to comment. And it would be a completely different question compared to the OP.